# Create Services and Factories and inject them to components using ES5

Tags: angular, angular2-services

How to create services and factories and inject them to component if Angular 2 code is written using ES5.

All the example online are using TypeScript. Please provide a simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a service this way using ng.core.Class:

```
    var service = ng.core.Class({
        constructor: function(){},
        simeMethod: function() {
            return 'hello';
        }
    });
```

And inject it this way in a component within the constructor property of the ng.core.Class of the component:

```
var component = ng.core
    .Component({
        selector: 'comp',
        template: '<div>test</div>',
        providers: [service]
    })
    .Class({
        constructor: [service, function(service) {
                   console.log(service.someMethod());
            }]
        });
```

Comment: what about factories?

Comment: You can however simulateur this using the provide function and the attribute useFactory...

Comment: No need to import `service` in the `declarations` section of the module? Can you also provide the necessary wiring in other parts of the application?